# How do I show different groups of radio buttons at different times in python using Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, radio-button

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import webbrowser
import random
import Tkinter    
"""Sets the time from the buttons into a list"""
def selectedHour():
    x = hour.get()
    if not wake_time:
        wake_time.append(x)
    else:
        wake_time[0] = x
    print wake_time
    count += 1

def selectedMinute():
    x = minute.get()
    if len(wake_time) == 1:
        wake_time.append(x)
    else:
        wake_time[1] = x
    print wake_time
    count += 1

def selectedPeriod():
    x = period.get()
    if len(wake_time) == 2:
        wake_time.append(x)
    else:
        wake_time[2] = x
    print wake_time
    count += 1

wake_time = []

"""Creates Buttons"""
hour = IntVar()
minute = IntVar()
period = StringVar()
hour.set(None)
minute.set(None)
period.set(None)

count = 1

if count == 1:
    radio12 = Radiobutton(app, text = 12, value = 12, variable = hour, command = selectedHour).pack()
elif count == 2:
    radio2 = Radiobutton(app, text = 0, value = 0, variable = minute, command = selectedMinute).pack()
else:
    radio3 = Radiobutton(app, text = 'am', value = 'am', variable = period, command = selectedPeriod).pack()

app.mainloop()
```

What is a way to make my buttons show up at different times depending on what count is equal to? What I want is when the first set of buttons if clicked, it shows a different set of buttons, and then once those are clicked, a third set pops up.

Comment: Python doesn't have Radiobuttons; are you using some kind of library?  If so, which?

Comment: Tkinter does have radiobuttons [link](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm)

Comment: yes sorry, I am using Tkinter.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you trying to have the user select a time [12:00 am/pm] or are do you want Tkinter to refresh a new frame/canvas when the user select hr, then minutes frame opens, then am/pm. You could have drop down menus to take care of this.

Comment: I'm trying to refresh the canas when the user selects hour, then minute, and then am/pm. Normally there would be 12 buttons for hour (one for each hour) and 60 for minutes and then 2 for am/pm but I shortened it for this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
"""Sets the time from the buttons into a list"""
def selectedHour(count):
    x = hour.get()
    if not wake_time:
        wake_time.append(x)
    else:
        wake_time[0] = x
    print wake_time
    count += 1
    frame2.tkraise() # brings frame to front

def selectedMinute(count):
    x = minute.get()
    if len(wake_time) == 1:
        wake_time.append(x)
    else:
        wake_time[1] = x
    print wake_time
    count += 1
    frame3.tkraise() # brings frame to front

def selectedPeriod(count):
    x = period.get()
    if len(wake_time) == 2:
        wake_time.append(x)
    else:
        wake_time[2] = x
    print wake_time
    count += 1
    frame4.tkraise() # brings frame to front

wake_time = []


"""Creates Buttons"""
app = Tk()

hour = IntVar()
minute = IntVar()
period = StringVar()
hour.set(None)
minute.set(None)
period.set(None)
frame1 = Frame(app)
frame2 = Frame(app)
frame3 = Frame(app)
frame4 = Frame(app)
for frame in (frame1, frame2, frame3, frame4):
    frame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='news') #set frame layout

count = 1


 # initial value


HOUR = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
MINUTE = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
PERIOD = ['AM','PM']

group1 = LabelFrame(frame1, text="Hour", padx=5, pady=5) #Hour Label
group1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

HRoption = OptionMenu(group1, hour, *HOUR, command = lambda x:selectedHour(count)) #dropdown menu for hours
HRoption.pack()

group2 = LabelFrame(frame2, text="Minute", padx=5, pady=5) #label for minutes
group2.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

MINOption = OptionMenu(group2, minute, *MINUTE, command = lambda x:selectedMinute(count)) #dropdown menu for minutes
MINOption.pack()

group3 = LabelFrame(frame3, text="Period", padx=5, pady=5)
group3.pack(padx=10, pady=10) #label for period

MINOption = OptionMenu(group3, period, *PERIOD, command = lambda x:selectedPeriod(count)) #dropdown menu for period
MINOption.pack()
frame1.tkraise() #start the first frame
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry can you explain to me why the method selectedHour() needs the "count" variable in there? Sorry I'm very new to this. Why didn't it work the way I did it? with the count += 1 to change which buttons are showing depending on what count is at

Comment: You have the function selectedHour() using count incrementing by 1 but without it having the parameter of count passed to it.

Comment: You have the function selectedHour() using count incrementing by 1 but without it having the parameter of count passed to it. Python runs line by line, so the if statements you had before will only run once, to go back is impossible, that is where functions come in they help so that you don't have to repeat yourself if you are doing something more than once. You could have also used a while loop that `while(count >=1)` and put the if statements inside that, but you would need a stop condition so the while loop stops running.